# firebase arduino uno + esp8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I am trying to make a project that can read data from usbsheild connected to arduino uno board then send them to firebase through esp8266.
But the libraries of firebase and esp8266wifi that i found are not for arduino uno but for the esp8266 board can anyone help me in this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**The best way you can do is connect it to a web and then use firebase-php library**

> https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php/blob/master/README.md

*insert this*

**Follow this as your guide**

> https://stilllot2learn.wordpress.com/2017/11/18/arduino_gps_gsm/comment-page-1/#comment-47

**Don't forget to create your FIREBASE ACCOUNT**

> look for **database secret** as your TOKEN under User and Permissions
>   TAB